# Python SET FUNCTIONS with TUPLES

Tags: python, list, set, tuples

The code below works, although I need the same functionality but instead of using sets I need to use tuples. Can anyone help?

```
word = {'h','e','l','l','o'}
letters = {'a','b','c','l','h'}
remainder = word - letters
print (remainder)
```

Thanks for taking to time to read this.

Comment: Remove the curly braces and you will have a tuple. Or replace the curly braces with `tuple(...)`.

Comment: when i do that the function no longer works

Comment: @idjaw: That fails at the `remainder = word - letters` line, since there is no subtraction operation defined for tuples.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Sure. Then the OP needs to put together a better question and provide a real [mcve].

Comment: You can't subtract tuples. Could you not cast to sets and back? What's the crucial tuple-y thing you're looking for, order? Immutability (there is a frozenset...)?

Comment: @JohnPaul Please edit your question to explain what your real problem is, and what the real solution is you are looking to achieve. Explain why it is you are trying to use a tuple in your solution. Follow the [mcve] guidelines.

Comment: i have repeating letters in the tuples, if i convert to sets i will loose letters

Comment: @idjaw: The question seems clear enough to me--the OP wants to get the equivalent result using tuples for the values and result rather than sets. He wants to implement exclusion without sets. The OP may be faulted for not showing enough effort, but he does show some code that comes close to accomplishing what he wants so that seemed good enough for me.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Then that's great for you that you read enough of it to want to answer it and provide a solution. My personal goal as a contributor here is to ensure that it meets some form of explicitness in terms of what is trying to be solved. Adding that extra bit of "The following code does <this>" and I would like to use <this data structure> instead, but I'm having difficulty accomplishing this". Something along those lines. It is more an attempt of providing constructive criticism to make clearer questions.

Comment: @RoryDaulton The goal is not to decipher enough of the question to be able to just write an answer but to also have a balance of being a positive contributor, enriching the other community members and then providing a good answer.

Answer (score 3):

Since tuples do not have a subtraction operator, you can use a generator expression that is quickly converted to a tuple. This code constructs a tuple from the values inside `word` but leaves out the values that are also in `letters`. One advantage of this over using sets is that the items are guaranteed to retain their order in `word`. The main disadvantage is that it is much slower for large tuples/sets, having time complexity `O(n**2)` rather than that of the sets solution which is `O(n)` (if both tuples/sets are of size `n`). One more thing to note is that this code retains any duplicate values that are in `word` but not in `letters` while the set solution removes duplicates--this may be a good or a bad thing, depending.

```
word = ('h','e','l','l','o')
letters = ('a','b','c','l','h')
remainder = tuple(v for v in word if v not in letters)
print(remainder)
```